# How can I make PyCharm ignore SSL errors when installing libraries?

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, ssl-certificate

I am trying to install the `requests` library to my Python environment in PyCharm while on a company network that uses self-signed SSL certificates. As a result, installing a library with `File > Settings > Project > Project Interpreter > Install` fails with an HTTPS error:

```
Collecting requests
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection
    broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.
    VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0368D5D0>: Failed to establish a new connection:
    [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/requests/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for requests
```

I tried making `pip` trust my company's root certificate by adding `--cert C:\COMPANY-CAROOT.pem` to my install options, which was interpreted as:

```
pip install --cert C:\COMPANY-CAROOT.pem requests
```

I also tried opening `File > Settings > Project > Server Certificates` and checking *Accept non-trusted certificates automatically*, but ran into the same issue.

**How can I get PyCharm to ignore SSL certificate errors when installing external libraries?**

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. The way I resolved it was by adding all the packages I wanted to install in a `.txt` file, e.g. `requirements.txt` containing all the package-names and their versions.

Then from the Terminal (can also be the PyCharm Terminal), I did:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org -r requirements.txt
```

The key here is the use of `--trusted-host`. Adding the packages in a file is just for convenience.
Alternatively you can create a `pip.ini` file and add the trusted hosts there.